# React context doesn't update value when updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to make a simple routing system. Either the user is authenticated or not. I'm trying to use hooks to achieve this but I'm not having the biggest success with it just yet.

`authProvider.tsx`

```
import React, {Dispatch, PropsWithChildren, SetStateAction, useContext, useState} from "react";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import {ref, child, get} from "firebase/database";
import { database, auth } from "../data/firebase";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Admin } from "../types/user.type";

interface AuthContext {
    user: Admin | undefined;
    setUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Admin>>;
    authenticateUser: (email: string, password: string) => void;
    authenticated: boolean;
    setAuthenticated: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}
const AuthContext = React.createContext<AuthContext>({} as AuthContext)

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<Admin>({} as Admin)
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const nav = useNavigate();

    const authenticateUser = (email: string, password: string):void=> {

        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then(async (userCredential) => {
                // Signed in
                const admin =  await fetchUserData(userCredential.user.uid)
                console.log(admin)
                if (admin?.role !== "Admin") return;
                setUser(user);
                setAuthenticated(true)
                return nav("/")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
            });

    }

    const fetchUserData = (uid: string): Promise<Admin | null> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const dbRef = ref(database);

            get(child(dbRef, `users/${uid}`))
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        resolve(snapshot.val() as Admin) ;
                          console.log(snapshot.val());
                    } else {
                        reject("Admin not found.")
                        //   console.log("No data available");
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject("There was an error fetching the admin data.")
                });
        })
    }


    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser, authenticated, setAuthenticated, authenticateUser }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

`App.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Routes, Navigate,BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { Home, Login } from "./pages";
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from "./providers/authProvider";

function App() {
    const {authenticated} = useAuth()
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <AuthProvider>
                {authenticated
                    ? (
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
                        </Routes>
                    )
                    :(
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
                            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/login" />}/>
                        </Routes>
                    )
                }
            </AuthProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I call `authenticateUser` from my login page. The function gets called as expected and the user object is logged in the console. Have I missed something in the documentation which led to `authenticated` not being updated in the `App.tsx`? It also doesn't refresh the page when calling `nav("/")` after setting `authenticated` to `true`.

Comment: Hav you tried `console.log()` inside the `.catch` of `authenticateUser()`? Maybe there's an error in the request and you're not handling it. Also try to simply do `nav("/")` instead of returning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `useAuth()` Hook which consumes the `AuthContext` outside of the actual context. In order to get the data from `AuthContext` you have to  wrap it around `<App />` in that case.

```
const auth = useAuth(); // outside of your authprovider

return (
    <AuthProvider> {/* your context definition component */}
        {/* You can only access the context INSIDE AuthProvider */}
        <ChildrenComponent />
        <ChildrenComponent />
        <ChildrenComponent />
        <ChildrenComponent />
    </AuthProvider>
)
```

do this in your `index.tsx` or whereever you call your `app.tsx`:

```
<AuthProvider>
    <App /> {/* useAuth() has now access to the context */}
</AuthProvider>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I must have read over this. For the future reader that has the same issue. Make sure you also navigate back to whichever route you'd like to redirect to.